# How to customize pointer lock controls in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Based on the pointer lock controls example 
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~lizy/mrdoob-three.js-ef5f05d/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

How can this example be modified so that we can go up and down using keys and zoom in and zoom out using the mouse wheel or keys?

Any other tips on customizing the pointer lock controls are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use switches to identify what key is being pressed. Add the corresponding eventListeners.

Keydown

```
var onKeyDown = function ( event ) {
    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = true;
            break;

        ...
    }
};

document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
```

KeyUp

```
var onKeyUp = function ( event ) {
    switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = false;
            break;

        ...
    }
};

document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );
```

MouseWheel

```
var onMouseWheel = function ( event ) {
    ...
};

this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
```